# Chart.Js is keeping old data after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I'm using VueJS 2.0, Laravel 5.3 and Chart.JS

I build the page by making AJAX requests with vue.js to Laravel to get the data and it returns a JSON object (some pages make multiple AJAX calls for different data sets). On the page in question the chart is built fine but when the user changes the date the page updates but chart.js still keeps the data from the previous date, which can be seen when rolling the mouse over the old area. Its the same

To better explain this I have a gif video here: http://recordit.co/reNXqjzjtr as you can see, it shows data from the 2017-01-08 which is correct for the date selected but when moving the mouse towards the centre it shows the old data from the default date 2017-01-09.

The function to make the AJAX request to Laravel(PHP):

```
        fetchEvents: function (date = null) {

            this.loading = true;

            this.$http.get('data/daily/' + this.selectedDate).then(function (response) {
                this.data = response.body;
                this.selectedDate = this.data.date;
                this.drawChart();
                this.loading = false;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

This function then calls darwChart():

```
        drawChart: function () {

            // code for Pie charts here, mostly the same as below

            // Compare against past dates
            var ctx3 = document.getElementById("previousDaysPolar");

            var data = [this.data.nxt_summary.total_count,
                        this.data.total_previous_week.data, 
                        this.data.total_previous_month.data, 
                        this.data.total_previous_year.data];

            var previousDays = new Chart(ctx3, {
                type: 'polarArea',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Selected Date: ' + this.data.date, 
                            'Previous Week: ' + this.data.total_previous_week.date, 
                            'Previous Month: ' + this.data.total_previous_month.date, 
                            'Previous Year: ' + this.data.total_previous_year.date],
                    datasets: [{
                            label: 'Order types',
                            data: data,
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(96, 110, 103, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(202, 207, 0, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(191, 180, 143, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(242, 239, 233, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(96, 110, 103, 1)',
                                'rgba(202, 207, 0, 1)',
                                'rgba(191, 180, 143, 1)',
                                'rgba(242, 239, 233, 1)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true
                }
            });

        }
```

As you can see from the video, this function seems to be working as expecting because it is updating the data and the data is past to the chart. Any ideas why its keeping the old data as well as the new?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clear the chart before drawing it with new data. That way new chart is drawn with the updated data only. From chart.js docs:

> `.clear()`
>
> Will clear the chart canvas. Used extensively internally between animation frames, but you might find it useful.
>
> // Will clear the canvas that myLineChart is drawn on
> `myLineChart.clear();`
> // => returns 'this' for chainability

See the documentation for [prototype methods](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods)